# Iterate Mediator over json arrays

Tags: json, loops, wso2, esb

I'd like to iterate the results array of a json message

```
{ 
   "results":[ 
      { 
         "category":"mdl", 
         "subcategory":"ip", 
         "ip":"103.14.120.121", 
         "subtype":"IP-MDL", 
         "date":"1405074556", 
         "longitude":"75.3333", 
         "latitude":"19.8833", 
         "country":"India", 
         "city":"Aurangabad", 
         "organization":"Good Domain Registry Private Limited", 
         "isp":"Good Domain Registry Private Limited" 
      }, 
      { 
         "category":"mdl", 
         "subcategory":"ip", 
         "ip":"108.162.198.96", 
         "subtype":"IP-MDL", 
         "date":"1405074556", 
         "longitude":"-122.3933", 
         "latitude":"37.7697", 
         "country":"United States", 
         "city":"San Francisco", 
         "organization":"CloudFlare", 
         "isp":"CloudFlare" 
      } 
   ] 
}
```

unfortunately iteration mediator doesn't seem to accept non xpath expression 
anyone knows how to iterate over the previous message json results the same way i do it in xml ?
I'd like to use ESB json-native support but doesn't seem to be able to break down json messages as with XML (i've tried iterate mediator, json payload factory and script mediator without any success)

```
            <iterate expression="json-eval(results)"> 
               <target> 
                  <sequence> 
                     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/> 
                     <payloadFactory media-type="json"> 
<format> 
{ 
"event":{ 
"providerName":"$1", 
"providerSource":"$2", 
"providerClassification":"$3", 
"providerVersion":"$4", 
"body":{ 
"results":{$5} 
} 
} 
} 
</format> 
<args> 
                                <arg value="bdigital"/> 
                                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.results.category"/> 
<arg evaluator="json" expression="$.results.subcategory"/> 
                                <arg value="1.0"/> 
                                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.results"/> 
</args> 
</payloadFactory> 
                     <call> 
                        <endpoint> 
                           <http method="post" 
                                 uri-template="http://BD-VM-PP-CIC01:8280/services/CICQueue"/> 
                        </endpoint> 
                     </call> 
                  </sequence> 
               </target> 
            </iterate>
```

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following?

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
      <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" continueParent="true" expression="//jsonObject/results" id="MyIterator">
         <target>
            <sequence>
               <property name="cat" expression="json-eval($.results.category)" type="STRING"></property>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version in WSO2 EI in which you can iterate over JSON using JSON Path. You can do something like below.

```
         <iterate id="iterate-over-users" preservePayload="true" attachPath="json-eval($.results)" expression="json-eval($.results)">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <http method="POST" uri-template="http://backend.com"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
```

Refer to the following blog for more info. https://medium.com/@arunans23/iterate-over-json-payload-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-8ccb9cdd2c70

Comment: how to access a sub element under results?